# Development environment for erlang on Windows

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, erlang, erlang-nif

I have an erlang project that includes NIFs with OS specific functions that work with raw sockets. I want to port this project on Windows which means changing the functions in NIFs to work on Windows.

What is the preferred IDE for erlang programming on Windows?

What do I have to set up in order to be able to compile this project?

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice to just down load cygwin with its gcc and try to compile your nif as you would on linux. There are some instructions on [github](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/INSTALL-WIN32.md) on how to setup an Windows environment to compile Erlang/OTP, but this is probably overkill for your NIF.

As an IDE I would use whatever you are using on Linux, i.e. hopefully Emacs :)

Answer (score 0):

Erlang can be set up as an external tool in msvc.